# PHP get file contents for textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that selects files from the server and then on change puts the filename and contents into text areas. This works fine if I have this in the base directory of /evo/ where everything is kept (as in /evo/users/username being where it pulls the files from) However when I moved this page deeper into the folder it has trouble parsing the files from the dropdown list. I had to add

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

To the file so it found the files to display in the dropdown correctly, however when it tries to put them into into the text area, it displays:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://mywebsite.site/home/revo/public_html/evo/users/Addiction/Addiction.html".
```

Which means either my directory in how I'm finding them is wrong or (hopefully and likely) how I'm echoing it or using it in the function change at the bottom is. The textarea that isn't loading correctly is the "CodeValue" box that displays the files contents.

```
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList"><option selected disabled>(Select Your Code)</option>
<?php
$directory = $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/evo/' . '/users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
$filesContents = Array();
$files = scandir( $directory ) ;

foreach( $files as $file )
{
if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
{
$filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
echo '<option value="'. $file .'">' . $file . '</option>';
}
}
?>
</select>
            <input type="hidden" name="CodeId" id="CodeId" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CodeDescription" size="40" maxlength="50" id="CodeName" value="" />
            <font color=#33A6A6>Code:</font>&nbsp;<input name="USER" value="" SIZE=40 name="CodeValue" id="CodeValue" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=hidden name="ACTION" value="says to"><input type=hidden name="WHOTO" value="ALL"><input type=submit value="Enter"><font size="-1"><font color=#33A6A6>Entrance:&nbsp;</font><input name="SAYS" value="Enters the room..."><font color=#33A6A6>History:&nbsp;</font><input name="HISTORY" value="20" size=2><font size="-1"><font color=#33A6A6>No Pics:&nbsp;</font><input name="NOPIC" value="1" type="checkbox" checked></form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // apply a change event
    $('#CodeList').change(function() {
      // update input box with the currently selected value
        $('#CodeName').val($(this).val());
        $.get( '<? echo $directory ?>' + '/' + $('#CodeName').val(), function( data ) {
         $( "#CodeValue" ).val( data );
        });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says the AJAX request went to this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.site/home/revo/public_html/evo/users/Addiction/Addiction.html
```

Whereas I think you wanted it to go to:

```
http://mywebsite.site/evo/users/Addiction/Addiction.html
```

Since you said `/evo/` is the base directory.  The script being output is including the internal directory path on the server rather than the externally visible HTTP path.  You can change this by doing this at the top:

```
$httpPath = '/evo/' . '/users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
$directory = $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $httpPath;
```

and then this in the script output:

```
$.get( '<? echo $httpPath ?>' + '/' + $('#CodeName').val(), function( data ) {
```

Comment: That was exactly it phari and exactly where I needed it to go. This resolved the issue. I didn't know to use httpPath. Thank you so much!